# Run a macro in excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Hi friends i am working on vss 2012, Excel 2013. I am trying to implement the Exporting of Grid view records to the Excel sheet. Excel sheet would be in good style. So what i did is i created a Macro of my  design in one excel sheet. So now i have the code of that particular macro.

Now i want to use this macro(Design) in new excel sheets also. Like say every day new records will be added to the grid view, and at the end of the day if i click on export to excel i a new excel should  get created with the design of macro, and all records. Is that possible??

What could be the difficulties in implementing this .. I could not find anything related to this in net. So please if anybody know this please let me know...

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a database...

Comment: I can normally do Gridview.rendercontrol(HtmltextWriter)..But i need that to be in different template, with some formulas which would fetch the full records details of particular user...

Answer (score 2):

You can insert VBA macro using this code:

```
    public void SetVBACode(string _macro)
    {
        VBProject project = workbook.VBProject;
        VBComponents components = project.VBComponents;           
        VBComponent component =components.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
        component.CodeModule.AddFromString(_macro);
    }
```

And run them using this method:

```
    public void RunVBACode(string _name)
    {
        excelApplication.RunVBACode(_name);
    }
```

Comment: please could you clarify input arguemnt of two methods...Is _macro is the path of my macro??

Comment: macro - is a test of vba macros as string;  _name - is the name of vba macros you want to launch

Comment: Is there a possibilty to fetch macro from one xlsm extension workbook, and run that in other worksheet???

Comment: I think VBComponents will help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443983(v=vs.60).aspx